# Can't figure out why appending to list isn't working

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm looping through a list to generate some json. But I have an error when i append to listToSave.

```
listToSave = []

for i in range(len(ffts)):

    dataT = dataTemplate

    dataT['aClip']['info']['id'] = str(uuid.uuid4())   
    #More stuff added here        

    print dataT['aClip']['info']['id']

    listToSave.append(dataT)

print 'Data formated - Ready to save'
```

And the output:

```
493838a3-de8e-4bc4-86a4-92999bd625bd
c7c6f984-85b5-478b-9395-48ebd8611ab8
d427dd05-063c-49de-bbff-70b09c56f1fa
98dc6ef5-182d-4963-bc0d-7537bd3ca9e2
74587d54-811c-485e-bbed-1428723a6da1
5052f46e-371d-4bec-b750-e231abd3448d
Data formated - Ready to save
```

But, when I look at listToSave list, I just see the last value generated repeated.

```
print len(toSave)

print toSave[0]['aClip']['info']['id']
print toSave[1]['aClip']['info']['id']
print toSave[2]['aClip']['info']['id']
print toSave[3]['aClip']['info']['id']
print toSave[4]['aClip']['info']['id']
print toSave[5]['aClip']['info']['id']
```

Output:

```
6
5052f46e-371d-4bec-b750-e231abd3448d
5052f46e-371d-4bec-b750-e231abd3448d
5052f46e-371d-4bec-b750-e231abd3448d
5052f46e-371d-4bec-b750-e231abd3448d
5052f46e-371d-4bec-b750-e231abd3448d
5052f46e-371d-4bec-b750-e231abd3448d
```

Help?

dataTemplate for a complete example. Although, I believe I tried it without this and it still ran.

```
dataTemplate = {
  "aClip": {
    "info" : {
      "id" : None,
      "type" : None,
      "author" : None,
      "timeStamp" : None,
      "output" : None,
    },
    "t": {
      "tData": None,
      "tFs" : None,
      "tLen" : None,
    },
    "f" : {
      "fData" : None,
      "fFreq" : None,
      "fLen" : None,
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `dataTemplate` never changes, therefore, your loop does the same thing on every iteration.

Comment: You have multiple references to the same object.

Comment: @SPYBUG96 How will that help?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your current code will not run because `dataTemplate` is not defined.

Comment: I'm guessing you were going to use `i` in conjunction with `dataTemplate` to do something different every turn?

Comment: `import copy;copy.deepcopy(dataTemplate) `

Comment: not sure why someone down-voted the question?

Comment: I've updated the code to include dataTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `dataT = dataTemplate`.

You probably believe you are creating and assigning a *new* dataTemplate object in each iteration of the loop. But, in fact, there's only one in the entire program.  Therefore, `dataT['aClip']['info']['id'] = str(uuid.uuid4())` is overwriting the same string each time, and you've added multiple references to the *same* dataTemplate.

Is `dataTemplate` a *class*?  If so, you can fix you program by changing `dataT = dataTemplate` to `dataT = dataTemplate()`.  If it's not a class, you'll need to explain what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You are appending to your list a **reference** to dataTemplate every time. If you check the memory addresses in your list you will find they point to same exact memory location.

Hence you will only have the last value.

I'm not sure what your `dataTemplate` is. If it's a class you need to create a new one each time. Same thing if it was a python dictionary or some JSON.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already stated, you are passing the same element with each iteration of the `for` loop. Although I don't know what `dataTemplate` looks like, it seems like you can use a `defaultdict`, assuming that `uuid` varies with `i`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dataT = defaultdict(str)

for i in range(len(ffts)):

    dataT[str(uuid.uuid4())] = 'somedata'
    #More stuff added here        

print('Data formated - Ready to save')
```